# Creating a NSColor with RGB value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, rgb

How do I create a NSColor from a RGB value?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per the [NSColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1526323-colorwithcalibratedred) documentation:

```
NSColor *myColor = [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:redValue green:greenValue blue:blueValue alpha:1.0f];
```

Comment: You should use 1.0f instead of 1.0, as 1.0 is a double, which is not a native type for the iPhone.

Comment: It's probably worth making it clear that the color values are from 0.0 to 1.0.

Also, the "calibrated" version is indeed more than likely the correct variant of this method to use.  You want to use the NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace (which corresponds to [NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace]) in all internal dealings with colors.  And only use the "device" color spaces variants when outputting to a known specific device.

Comment: @nash - there's no NSColor type on the iPhone, NSColor is part of Cocoa on the OSX

Comment: Note that on modern hardware it can be important to specify a color space -- e.g. a red component of 1.0 in the default sRGB space is less red than a red component of 1.0 in the Display P3 space supported by newer Mac displays. Use the [newer initializers on NSColor](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscolor#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSColor/gridColor) to be explicit about which space you're using.

Answer (score 12):

Also don't forget to do the following conversion from the actual RGB values you get, lets say from Photoshop...

an RGB of (226, 226, 226) could be instantiated as a NSColor using the values:

```
Red:   226/255 = 0.886... 
Green: 226/255 = 0.886...
Blue:  226/255 = 0.886... 

[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.886f green:0.886f blue:0.886f alpha:1.0f];
```

Why 255? 8-bit color channels range from 0 to 255 (inclusive). When normalized this is scaled to the range [0,1] (inclusive). See references for conversions from normalized values to unnormalized values and vice versa.

## References

- [OpenGL ES Full Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/1.1/es_full_spec_1.1.12.pdf), See Table 2.7 on Page 38
- [Unreal Engine Color Conversion](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Runtime/Core/Private/Math/Color.cpp)

Comment: This might be obvious to everyone else, but why the +1? Is it just because 256 is a nicer number to divide with, more factors, thus less rounding errors / decimal points?

Comment: This answer is slightly wrong. 8-bit RGB color component values range from 0 to 255, which is 256 values in total. Thus the correct way to map to RGB values ranging from 0 to 1 is to divide by 255, ie: `red = 226 / 255`. Adding the awkward-looking 1 and dividing by 256 gives very similar but slightly incorrect results, which you can verify by considering what would happen if a color component were 0: zero divided by 255 is still zero, but `(0 + 1) / 256` > 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
float red = 0.5f;
float green = 0.2f;
float blue = 0.4f;
float alpha = 0.8f;

NSColor *rgb = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];
```

Answer (score -3):

**Extension for Swift 2**

```
extension NSObject {
    func RGB(r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b:CGFloat, alpha:CGFloat? = 1) -> NSColor {
        return NSColor(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: alpha!)
    }
}
```

Then just call

```
RGB(r: 16, g: 105, b: 125)
```

or

```
RGB(r: 16, g: 105, b: 125, alpha: 0.5)
```

Comment: Why create an extension of NSObject and not of NSColor?

Comment: but if you create an extension of NSObject, you need to call the function like this: NSObject().RGB(_:, g:, b:) or any NSObject subclass

Comment: Yes, but just inside NSObject subclass, so Objective-C classes, but not inside pure Swift classes, from global functions or from top level code. And also, you call the function without naming the `r` parameter.